# How to register an event using termios.h in a class

Tags: c++, termios

I'm making a c++ serial class in Linux.  I'm trying to register an event when incoming data is received.

I'm working on a Olimex Lime2 board.
gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14)

This is the error i get when trying to compile.
conSerial.cpp: In function ‘void signal_handler_IO(int)’:
conSerial.cpp:15:6: error: ‘EventHandler’ was not declared in this scope

I think this means that it doesn't have access to the class.  Perhaps I've gone about this the wrong way.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Steve

Header File

```
#ifndef CONSERIAL_H_
#define CONSERIAL_H_

#include "termios.h"
#include <sys/signal.h>
class conSerialEvents
{
    public:
        virtual void onReceive();
};
class conSerial
{
    public:
        conSerial(const char *port_, termios *options_, conSerialEvents *EventHandler_);
        conSerial(const char *port_, termios *options_);
        int open_port(void);
        int send(const char *s, size_t len);
        void close_port( void );
    private:

        conSerialEvents *EventHandler;
        static const int PORT_OPEN = 0;
        termios *options;
        const char *port;
        int fd;
        struct sigaction saio;  
};

#endif
```

Class File

```
#include <stdio.h>      //Standard input/output definitions
#include <string.h>     //String function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     //UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      //File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      //Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>    //POSIX terminal control definitions
#include <iostream>     //Input-Output Streams
#include "conSerial.h"  //Header for this file
using namespace std;
void signal_handler_IO (int status);
void signal_handler_IO (int status)
{
    std::cout << "Signal" << std::endl;
    //This section fails because it can't see the class I think.
    if (EventHandler)
    {
        EventHandler->onReceive();
    }
    //End this section

}

conSerial::conSerial(const char *port_, termios *options_)
{
    this->EventHandler = 0L;
    const char *port;
    termios *options;
    fd = -1;

}

conSerial::conSerial(const char *port_, termios *options_, conSerialEvents *EventHandler_)
{
    this->EventHandler = EventHandler_;
    const char *port;
    termios *options;
    fd = -1;
} 

int conSerial::open_port(void){

    struct termios options;

    fd = open("/dev/ttyS1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if (fd == -1){
        //Could not open the port.
        std::cout << "Port Failed to Open";
    }else{
        saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
        sigemptyset(&saio.sa_mask);
        saio.sa_flags = 0;
        saio.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER;
        saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
        sigaction(SIGIO,&saio,NULL);

        fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());      
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY); // Sets the read() function to return NOW and not wait for data to enter buffer if there isn't anything there.

        //Configure port for 8N1 transmission
        tcgetattr(fd, &options);                    //Gets the current options for the port
        cfsetispeed(&options, B38400);              //Sets the Input Baud Rate
        cfsetospeed(&options, B38400);              //Sets the Output Baud Rate
        options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);        //? all these set options for 8N1 serial operations
        options.c_cflag |= PARENB;                  //? 
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;                 //?
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;                  //?
        options.c_cflag |= CS7;                     //?

        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);           //Set the new options for the port "NOW"

        std::cout << "seems like everything is ok, keep going\n";
    };

    return (fd);
};

int conSerial::send(const char *s, size_t len){
    int written;
    written = 0;
    if (fd==-1){    //
        // If this is -1 it means that the port is not open.
        std::cout << "The port is not open." << std::endl;
    }else{
        // The port is open
        tcdrain(fd);
        written = write(fd, s, len);
    }
    return written;
}

void conSerial::close_port( void ){
    if (fd !=-1){
        close(fd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "Class File", you declared a function:

```
void signal_handler_IO (int status)
```

which refers to some object called "EventHandler".

No such object is declared anywhere, hence the compilation error. It's as simple as that.

It is true that you declared a class named "conSerial", which happens to have a class member called "EventHandler".

However, that's a class right there. And a class member. The fact that you have some class that happens to declare a class member of the same name makes absolutely no difference, whatsoever. C++ doesn't work this way. `signal_handler_IO` is not a method in the same class. It is not even a static class function in that class. To access a class member you need one of two things: either an instance of a class, somewhere, in order to access its member; or access it from a non-static method in the same class, which automatically access the corresponding member of whatever class instance whose method it is. That's how C++ works.

And that's the fundamental explanation for your compilation error.

It is true that in a different class method called "open_port", you take a pointer to this `signal_handler_IO` function, and install it as a signal handler for `SIGIO`. Again, that doesn't really change anything.

It appears that you intend your `conSerial` class to be a singleton. In that case, the cleanest solution for your conundrum is:

1. Refactor the class so that it's construction and destruction [uses the singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern), as much as possible.
2. Install the signal handler in the class's constructor, and uninstall the signal handler in its destructor.
3. Have the constructor save a pointer to `this` in a private static class member, before installing the signal handler.
4. Move the bulk of `signal_handler_IO` into a static class method, and have `signal_handler_IO` do nothing except invoke the static class method.
5. Have you static class method use the pointer that was set up in step 3 access the actual instance of your singleton class. Now, it can do whatever it wants to do with its "EventHandler" class member.